# Assembly: Print information from AL, AH and BH

Tags: assembly, tasm

Need to get information about the current video mode. Function `0fh` returns this info in `AL`, `AH` and `BH` registers. How to print information (in decimal format) from this registers?

Thanks for answer.

```
.model tiny
.code

org 100h 
start:
    mov ah,9
    lea dx, select_video_mode_msg 
    int 21h
    call readsymb

change_video_mode:
    mov ah,00h
    int 10h 

change_video_page_msg:
    mov ah,9
    lea dx, select_video_page_msg 
    int 21h
    call readsymb

change_video_page:
    mov ah,05h
    int 10h 

print_info:
    mov ah,0fh
    int 10h 
    ; print info from AL, AH, BH

endprog:
    ret


readsymb:
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h 
    cmp al,2fH 
    jz endprog
    cmp al,'0'
    jz endprog 
    cmp al,'9'
    ja endprog 
    xor ah,ah 
    sub al,30h 
    ret

.data
select_video_mode_msg   db  'Select video mode (0-7): ','$'
select_video_page_msg   db  'Select video page: ','$'
info_msg_cols           db  'Symbs cols: ','$' 
info_msg_mode           db  'Current mode: ','$' 
info_msg_page           db  'Current page: ','$' 
md                      db  '$'


end start
```

Comment: It can't be done without writing code.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, added my code.

Comment: 1) Convert AL, AH, BH values to ASCII strings 2) Print them as you do with the other strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sooo many explanations and examples for this task in the net. The trick is to repeatedly divide the register by 10 and store the remainder. Here is my suggestion especially for your needs:

```
.MODEL tiny
.CODE
ORG 100h

start:

    call print_info

    mov ax, 4C00h                   ; Exit(0)
    int 21h


print_info:
    mov ah,0fh                      ; GET CURRENT VIDEO MODE
    int 10h                         ; Call Video-BIOS
    mov WORD PTR HOLD_AL, ax        ; This affects also HOLD_AH
    mov HOLD_BH, bh

    ; AL
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    lea dx, INFO1                   ; Pointer to string
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS
    mov al, HOLD_AL                 ; Argument for al2dec
    call al2dec                     ; Convert AL to decimal-string
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    mov dx, di                      ; Result of al2dec
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS

    ; AH
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    lea dx, INFO2                   ; Pointer to string
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS
    mov al, HOLD_AH                 ; Argument for al2dec
    call al2dec                     ; Convert AL to decimal-string
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    mov dx, di                      ; Result of al2dec
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS

    ; BH
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    lea dx, INFO3                   ; Pointer to string
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS
    mov al, HOLD_BH                 ; Argument for al2dec
    call al2dec                     ; Convert AL to decimal-string
    mov ah, 09h                     ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    mov dx, di                      ; Result of al2dec
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS

    ret

al2dec:
    mov bl, 10                      ; Base 10 -> divisor
    lea di, DEC_END
  L1:
    dec di                          ; fill the decimal-string in reverse order
    xor ah, ah                      ; Clear AH for division
    div bl                          ; AL = AX / BL   Remainder AH
    or ah, 30h                      ; Convert AH to ASCII
    mov BYTE PTR [di], ah           ; Save AH in the decimal-string
    test al, al                     ; AL == 0?
    jnz L1                          ; No: once more
    ret                             ; Return DS:DI Pointer to the decimal-string


            DB  "000"               ; String
    DEC_End EQU $                   ;   with label pointing to its end (+1)
            DB 13, 10, '$'          ;   and line feed and '$'-terminator
    INFO1   DB "AL (display mode): $"
    INFO2   DB "AH (number of character columns): $"
    INFO3   DB "BH (active page): $"
    HOLD_AL DB ?                    ; Uninitialized space for saving AL
    HOLD_AH DB ?                    ; Uninitialized space for saving AH
    HOLD_BH DB ?                    ; Uninitialized space for saving BH

END start
```